# Jenkins: Can't perform copy-item to a shared folder

Tags: jenkins, shared-directory, copy-item

Why Jenkins won't be able to perform copy-item which destination is a shared folder. Jenkins can't recognize the path, it returns false when I test-path it but with my local machine the path is correct. I already run the powershell script as admin, anything I am missing of.

Comment: Is the shared folder also on Windows computer?

Comment: Yes @KristinaBankova.

Comment: What is the ID Jenkins is running as? Does the ID have access to the the shared folder you are trying to copy to?

Comment: I would recommend logging in as the Jenkins ID to the box and try accessing the path or execute the powershell command